# Batch - CMD.exe /T parameter option not setting colors as expected

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parameters

In the absence of `msg.exe` on my OS, I'm trying to imitate the pop-up message box using `cmd.exe`. But what I've encountered is bugging me senseless.

My ultimate goal is to programmatically, using a `.vbs` script and `schtasks.exe` create a pop-up reminder in the Task Scheduler.

The issue I have, is if I run the following in a batch file:

```
start "Alert" cmd.exe /t:f0 /k "mode con: cols=40 lines=10 & echo *** Message goes here *** & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo Press any key to exit & pause>nul"
```

I get the desired outcome, however, if I change the `/k` parameter to `/c` (as intended in the original script) the selected foreground/background colors fail to display correctly...

I get around this by changing the script to:

```
start "Alert" cmd.exe /c "mode con: cols=40 lines=10 & color f0 & echo *** Message goes here *** & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo Press any key to exit & pause > nul"
```

But I don't understand why the `/t` fails in my original script. Could someone explain?

As a related question - not sure if this is permitted, in which case ignore - Task Scheduler allows the manual creation of a "Display a message" action, is this achieved within the application itself? and is it possible to set it programmatically via `schtasks.exe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding `cmd.exe` ignoring `/t` when specifying `/k` - indeed that seems like a cmd.exe bug, I can confirm on a Windows 10 release 1607. Don't hold your breath for a fix...

Regarding `schtasks.exe` - there are some scheduled task features you can't create directly via command-line params. As a workaround, you can create such a task manually, export it, maybe edit the exported xml, and then re-create it using `schtasks /Create /XML mytask.xml`. Beware that `Display a message` is stated as ***(deprecated)***, so it may not work in future versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium, by the way. If this is indeed a bug, then I will definitely consider your work-around - does it mean the "Display a message" action is a process intrinsic to TS or does it call another app to execute the pop-up message? Do you think it's too early to report this bug to MS, or even worthwhile?

Comment: Okay, I've determined, by manually creating the task I aim to do programmatically, that when the message window is triggered no new process appears in task manager, the pop-up appears to be intrinsic to TS (taskeng.exe) itself :( ...I have also determined the command line "start" preceding the "cmd.exe" is not accepted in the "program/script" field, nor the "add arguments" field, the intention for this was changing the cmd window title, at least this I can do with the "title" parameter within the run command option itself...

Comment: Confirmed, `cmd.exe` ignores `/t` when `/c` is specified. Test this yourself by running `cmd /t:3F dir` (changes color) vs `cmd /t:3F /c dir` (no color change).